# Undefining a variable set as a default value in a function argument list PHP

Tags: php

EDIT: I want the default value of the argument to a function as undefined, so that when there is no argument passed to the function the return value of isset($argument) is equals to TRUE

I am not sure if I know the correct nomenclature, but what I need to do is this inside a class :

```
public function something ( $myvariable = unset ($myvariable) ){
    if ( isSet ( $myvariable ) ) //do something
    else //do something else
}
```

I know I can check for null if I set it like `$myvariable = NULL`, but I want to keep the coding style constant through out the website if possible.

How do I do it ?

Comment: You'r question doesen't really make any sense. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to have the default value undefined then `function something($myvariable = NULL)` is the way to go.

Comment: @axiac NULL != undefined or is it ?

Comment: For all practical purposes in PHP, `$x = NULL` is the same as undefined (`$x` was never initialized) and is the same as unset (after `unset($x)`). See the [PHP type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows from the first table).

Comment: @axiac thanks for the link